# the map interface android not clear

Tags: java, android

I have been following tutorials. However I am stuck on this line, can't seem to understand what it means/does..
Can someone give me explanation please.

```
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=
```

is a field declaration

```
new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>()
```

is creating a `HashMap` that uses `WeakReference`s from its keys to its values

```
Collections.synchronizedMap();
```

is creating a synchronized wrapper over the passed Map (in your case `WeakHashMap`)